# Optimising Algorithm

Tags: c++, optimization, variable-assignment

I need to optimise this function, but im stumped on ideas to improve on its speed...

```
bool generateShortestpathLink (const string& start, const string& finish, const book& db) {
    vector <lib> bks;
    vector <string> authors;
    set <lib> storeBKS;
    set <string> storeAuthor;
    queue <pathLink> q;

    pathLink p(start);
    q.push(p);

    while (!q.empty()) {

        p = q.front();

        if (p.getLength() > 6) return false;
        db.getTitles(p.getLastPlayer(), bks);

        for (int x = 0; x < (int) bks.size(); x++) {

            const film& newBook = bks[x];
            if (storeBKS.find(newBook) != storeBKS.end()) continue; 
            db.getAuthors(newBook, authors);
            storeBKS.insert(newBook);

            for (int i = 0; i < (int) authors.size(); i++) {

                if (storeAuthor.find(authors[i]) != storeAuthor.end()) continue;  
                pathLink newpathLink(p);
                newpathLink.addConnection(newBook, authors[i]); 
                if (authors[i] == finish) return true;
                storeAuthor.insert(authors[i]);
                q.push(newpathLink);
            }
        }
        q.pop();
    }

    return false;
}
```

it's suppose to be an algo for BFS, where it creates the path used to connect different titles of books with authors. `getTitles()` and `getAuthors` are both binary search functions that cannot be changed. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'm seeing is that you're not pre-allocating any memory. This is the first thing to do when optimizing an algorithm where you can't change the algorithm. You should find out how much memory those structures will need and immediately allocate it all at once to prevent them from having to reallocate repeatedly.

Also, consider using a sorted vector instead of a `set`. This will improve the look-up times quite considerably- just don't insert too often or you'll hurt.

Comment: I cant preallocate any memory to it because I'm generating a path from scratch with different sizes each time (depending on how many branches of connectors I make per lvl)

Comment: Then assume a reasonable maximum size of the path, preallocate the memory for it, and if it turns out that you need a bigger path, extend the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have specifically ruled out the biggest optimizations by saying that `getTitles()` can't be touched. You have a loop inside a loop inside a loop. The middle loop appears to be the culprit. As is, `getTitles()` mandates a linear search algorithm. You can't optimize something if the source of the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: is there any other methods i could use to improve getTitles(), it can be changed if required, but the specs do say I shouldn't need to touch it

Comment: Make it return something such as a `std::set` that doesn't mandate a linear search. The same goes for the authors of a book. That too mandates a linear search because it too is implemented as returning a `std::vector`.

Comment: I can't change the return type (stuck with vectors) would perphaps using pointers to add the paths together increase the speed?